# Is it possible to encrypt mpeg-dash clear content in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, aes, mpeg-dash

Is it possible to encrypt mpeg-dash clear content in ffmpeg? or do we need to additional code to handle the encryption?

From ffmpeg dashenc.c code it appears that dash code does not encrypt the content. 
Can we reuse the mp4 muxer for encrypting and dash for segmenting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg and openssl to create an AES encrypted HLS stream if this meets your needs - the ffmpeg documentation (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-34) includes this example script:

```js
#!/bin/sh
BASE_URL=${1:-'.'}
openssl rand 16 > file.key
echo $BASE_URL/file.key > file.keyinfo
echo file.key >> file.keyinfo
echo $(openssl rand -hex 16) >> file.keyinfo
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -c:v h264 -hls_flags delete_segments \
  -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo out.m3u8
```

You can also use mp4Box (https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/encryption/common-encryption/) to create basic clear DASH encryptions:

> MP4Box -crypt drm_file.xml movie.mp4 -out movie_encrypted.mp4

The drm info is included in the drm_file.xml and is explained at the link above.

Comment: I was looking more at mpeg-dash encryption with ffmpeg; reason is because mp4box expects input to be in the mp4 format and ffmpeg does not restrict input...Seems like the ffmpeg has the code in place but mpeg-dash code needs some refinement to handle the encryption. The existing dash code as we speak does not handle encryption.Thank you for the response.